# Tango Java SDK: onFrameAvailable not being called

Tags: java, android, google-project-tango

I'm trying to create a small application which both retrieves depth data and shows a little "preview" from my RGB camera.
Here's the code of my MainScreen class:

```
private static final String TAG = MainScreen.class.getSimpleName();

public static TangoConfig mConfig;
public static Tango mTango;
public TangoCameraPreview preview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    preview = new TangoCameraPreview(this);
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.content_main_screen);
    layout.addView(preview);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    preview.disconnectFromTangoCamera();
    mTango.disconnect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    preview.onPause();
    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            mTango.disconnect();
        } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_tango_error), e);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mTango = new Tango(MainScreen.this, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (MainScreen.this) {
                try {
                    mConfig = setupTangoConfig(mTango);
                    mTango.connect(mConfig);
                    preview.connectToTangoCamera(mTango, TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR);
                    startupTango();


                } catch (TangoOutOfDateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_out_of_date), e);
                } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_tango_error), e);
                } catch (TangoInvalidException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.exception_tango_invalid), e);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    preview.onResume();
}

private TangoConfig setupTangoConfig(Tango tango) {
    TangoConfig config = tango.getConfig(TangoConfig.CONFIG_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_LOWLATENCYIMUINTEGRATION, true);
    config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DEPTH, true);
    config.putInt(TangoConfig.KEY_INT_DEPTH_MODE, TangoConfig.TANGO_DEPTH_MODE_POINT_CLOUD);
    return config;
}

private void startupTango() {
    final ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair> framePairs =
            new ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair>();



    mTango.connectListener(framePairs, new Tango.OnTangoUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPoseAvailable(final TangoPoseData pose) {
            // We are not using TangoPoseData for this application.
        }

        @Override
        public void onXyzIjAvailable(TangoXyzIjData xyzIj) {
            // We are not using onXyzIjAvailable for this app.
        }

        @Override
        public void onPointCloudAvailable(final TangoPointCloudData pointCloudData) {
            logPointCloud(pointCloudData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTangoEvent(final TangoEvent event) {
            // Ignoring TangoEvents.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFrameAvailable(int cameraId) {
            if(cameraId == TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR) {
                preview.onFrameAvailable();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void logPointCloud(TangoPointCloudData pointCloudData) {
    Log.i(TAG, String.format(getString(R.string.log_pointcloud_data),
            pointCloudData.numPoints,
            calculateAveragedDepth(pointCloudData.points, pointCloudData.numPoints)));
}

private float calculateAveragedDepth(FloatBuffer pointCloudBuffer, int numPoints) {
    float totalZ = 0;
    float averageZ = 0;
    if (numPoints != 0) {
        int numFloats = 4 * numPoints;
        for (int i = 2; i < numFloats; i = i + 4) {
            totalZ = totalZ + pointCloudBuffer.get(i);
        }
        averageZ = totalZ / numPoints;
    }
    return averageZ;
}
```

When I start this code, the TangoCameraPreview stays empty, and the onFrameAvailable()-Method is never called.

I have included Camera persmissions in my Android manifest xml, but it still isn't calling the handler.

Sadly, I haven't found any good tutorials on this topic, and since this is just a first step in my project, I don't want to write my own renderer just yet, if at all.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

after startup Tango make a call to 'connectTextureId':

```
tango.ConnectTextureId(TangoCameraIntrinsics.TangoCameraColor, -1);
```